# Interaction of services in the service layer

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design, service-layer

What is the best way to organize interaction between services in the service layer?
For example, I have document service and product service. In my case products can have their own documents and to manage documents of product I call appropriate methods from the document service in the product service. So, I need to create instance of document service in product service. And I need to call some methods from product service in the document service too. So, each of these services refers to other and I get stackoverflowexception respectively.
Which design solutions should I use to eliminate these problem?

Comment: It doesn't sound very DDD to me what you have there. About the design solutions isn't that your job as a developer?

Answer (score 1):

Application Services are supposed to provide external clients an API for executing cohesive business operations. An application service method generally matches a use case of your application.

While an application service operation may require calling another service (eg, the `Create Product` use case includes the `Create Document` use case, which can also be called separately), this is not the norm and you should look to make your application services as cohesive as possible. In particular, just because at some point in your business case you start to manipulate another kind of entity doesn't mean you should delegate that part to another application service - in other words, *one application service per entity* is not necessarily right.

In any case, from your domain it should appear clearly in which direction the dependency between 2 applications services points. In your example, Product Service seems to depend on Document Service - it's difficult to imagine why it would be the other way around.

If you really need a round-trip between service A and service B (which I wouldn't do unless I have no other option), you could try and have the instance of A inject itself into B instead of relying on a DI container to resolve the dependency with a new instance, solving the stack overflow problem - if that's why you get a stack overflow in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, **circular dependencies are wrong**.

You can use [shared identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) to decouple `Product`s and `Document`s.

Moreover you can orchestrate the service interaction from outside them, in the application: in the ProductService you can have a `LoadProducts(ProductIdentifiers[] identifiers)` returning an immutable collection of products and in the DocumentService you can have a `LoadDocuments(DocumentIdentifiers[] identifiers)` returning an immutable collection of documents.